# Add heteroatom to pdb file

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, pymol

I am using Biopython to perform various operations on a pdb file. Subsequently I would like to add some new atoms to the Biopython structure object generated by Biopython. Is there a good/recommended way to do this in Python. It seems Biopython only provides options to write out existing elements of a pdb file and not to create new ones.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at the Python package *Biotite* (https://www.biotite-python.org/), a package I am developing.
In the following example code, a PDB structure is downloaded, read and then an atom is added:

```py
import biotite.database.rcsb as rcsb
import biotite.structure as struc
import biotite.structure.io as strucio


# Download lysozyme structure for example
file_name = rcsb.fetch("1aki", "pdb", target_path=".")

# Read the file into Biotite's structure object (atom array)
atom_array = strucio.load_structure(file_name)

# Add an HETATM
atom = struc.Atom(
    coord = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
    chain_id = "A",
    # The residue ID is the last ID in the file +1
    res_id = atom_array.res_id[-1] + 1,
    res_name = "ABC",
    hetero = True,
    atom_name = "CA",
    element = "C"
)
atom_array += struc.array([atom])

# Save edited structure
strucio.save_structure("1aki_edited.pdb", atom_array)
```

The last lines of `1aki_edited.pdb`:

```
...
HETATM 1075 O    HOH A 203      12.580  21.214   5.006  1.00 0.000          O   
HETATM 1076 O    HOH A 204      19.687  23.750  -4.851  1.00 0.000          O   
HETATM 1077 O    HOH A 205      27.098  35.956 -12.358  1.00 0.000          O   
HETATM 1078 O    HOH A 206      37.255   9.634  10.002  1.00 0.000          O   
HETATM 1079 O    HOH A 207      43.755  23.843   8.038  1.00 0.000          O   
HETATM 1080 CA   ABC A 208       1.000   2.000   3.000  1.00 0.000          C
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used RDKit to add and edit atoms in PDB-files succesfully. Below I've shown a small example of how to add a carbon atom to a PDB-file and creating a new .pdb-file

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import rdGeometry

prot = Chem.MolFromPDBFile("./3etr.pdb") #Read in the .pdb-file
protconf = prot.GetConformer() #create a conformer of the molecule

#create an editable mol-object
mw = Chem.RWMol(mol)

#create an editable conformer. This dictates the atoms coordinates and other attributes
mw_conf = mw.GetConformer() 

#add a carbon atom to the editable mol. Returns the index of the new atom, which is the same as prot.GetNumAtoms() + 1
c_idx = mw.AddAtom(Chem.Atom(6))  

#cartesian coordinates of the new atom. I think the Point3D object is not strictly necessary. but can be easier to handle in RDKit
coord = rdGeometry.Point3D(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)

#set the new coordinates
mw_conf.SetAtomPosition(c_idx, coord) 

#save the edited PDB-file
pdb_out = Chem.MolToPDBFile(mw_conf, "_out.pdb")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok **USING BioPython**, given input file pdb as `test_2.pdb` :

```
ATOM      1  N   THR A   1      32.504  37.205  19.346  1.00 35.93           N  
ATOM      2  CA  THR A   1      33.806  36.685  19.869  1.00 33.83           C  
ATOM      3  C   THR A   1      35.000  37.216  19.097  1.00 34.05           C  
ATOM      4  O   THR A   1      34.831  37.956  18.112  1.00 37.45           O  
ATOM      5  CB  THR A   1      33.780  35.136  19.858  1.00 35.93           C  
ATOM      6  OG1 THR A   1      34.996  34.712  20.476  1.00 29.78           O  
ATOM      7  CG2 THR A   1      33.677  34.608  18.436  1.00 28.68           C  
ATOM      8  N   ASN A   2      36.222  36.900  19.493  1.00 27.70           N  
ATOM      9  CA  ASN A   2      37.466  37.312  18.870  1.00 26.38           C  
ATOM     10  C   ASN A   2      37.890  36.323  17.772  1.00 23.63           C  
ATOM     11  O   ASN A   2      37.108  35.426  17.477  1.00 26.11           O  
ATOM     12  CB  ASN A   2      38.573  37.472  19.903  1.00 26.18           C  
ATOM     13  CG  ASN A   2      38.854  36.188  20.687  1.00 23.57           C  
ATOM     14  OD1 ASN A   2      38.219  35.168  20.445  1.00 24.27           O  
ATOM     15  ND2 ASN A   2      39.763  36.310  21.648  1.00 25.69           N  
ATOM     16  N   ALA A   3      39.078  36.497  17.205  1.00 27.65           N  
ATOM     17  CA  ALA A   3      39.537  35.641  16.112  1.00 27.70           C  
ATOM     18  C   ALA A   3      39.734  34.176  16.518  1.00 27.15           C  
ATOM     19  O   ALA A   3      39.174  33.270  15.869  1.00 26.97           O  
ATOM     20  CB  ALA A   3      40.807  36.208  15.498  1.00 27.00           C  
ATOM     21  N   THR B   1      40.123  33.960  17.768  1.00 24.83           N  
ATOM     22  CA  THR B   1      40.236  32.608  18.357  1.00 21.65           C  
ATOM     23  C   THR B   1      38.868  31.997  18.531  1.00 22.46           C  
ATOM     24  O   THR B   1      38.571  30.833  18.173  1.00 22.18           O  
ATOM     25  CB  THR B   1      40.984  32.761  19.690  1.00 19.96           C  
ATOM     26  OG1 THR B   1      42.296  33.274  19.425  1.00 28.59           O  
ATOM     27  CG2 THR B   1      41.111  31.396  20.390  1.00 23.74           C
```

and code, kind of long with lots of prints out to try to explaind what is going on :

```
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser

from Bio.PDB.Chain import Chain

from Bio.PDB.Residue import Residue

from Bio.PDB.Atom import Atom

from Bio.PDB.PDBIO import PDBIO, Select

import numpy as np


from Bio import  __version__


print('########## Biopython  VERSION #####################################')
print('\n BIOPYTHON_VERSION : ', __version__ ,'\n')
print('###################################################################')

structure = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE = False , QUIET=False).get_structure('X', 'test_2.pdb')

        
print('\n---------------------------------------------------\n')



atom_list = structure.get_atoms()  ## its actually a generator , that get emptied when cycled

print('atom_list : \n ', [i for i in atom_list],'\n\n')


atom_list = structure.get_atoms() ## its actually a generator , that get emptied when cycled

print('atom      ----------------> serial number')

for atom in atom_list:
    
    print( atom ,' -----------> ' ,  atom.get_serial_number() , atom.get_parent().resname , atom.get_parent().id[1])
    
    print(atom.get_full_id(),'\n')
    

    

print('\n ________________________')    
chain_list = set([resi.get_parent().id for resi in structure.get_residues()])

print('chain_list : ', chain_list) 

print('list(chain_list)[0] : ', list(chain_list)[0])

print('\n ________________________')   
chains = [resi.get_parent() for resi in structure.get_residues()]

print('chains : ', chains)

print('set(chains) : ', set(chains))

print('list(set(chains))[0] : ', list(set(chains))[0])  


chainss = []


print('\n ________________________')
for resi in structure.get_residues() :
    
    if resi.get_parent() not in chainss :
        
        chainss.append(resi.get_parent())
        
print('chainss : ', chainss)
    


print('\n ________________________')

res_max = max([resi.id[1] for resi in chainss[-1].get_residues()])

print('res_max in chain : ', chainss[-1] , ' ---> ', res_max)
    
print('\n ________________________')    
atom_max =  max([atom.serial_number for atom in structure.get_atoms()]) 

print('atom_max : ', atom_max)


"""

x = Residue((' ',999,' '), 'POP', " ") ##see https://biopython.org/wiki/The_Biopython_Structural_Bioinformatics_FAQ#what-is-a-residue-id


"""
print('\n ________________________')  
for res in structure.get_residues() :
    
    print('res.get_full_id() : ', res.get_full_id() , ' res.id : ' , res.id)

    print('res.get_resname() : ', res.get_resname())
    
    print('res.get_segid() : ', res.get_segid())
    
    print('res.get_parent() : ', res.get_parent())    


new_res = Residue(('H' , res_max+1 , ' ') , 'XYZ' , " ")


# new_atm = Atom(name, coord, bfactor, occupancy, altloc, fullname, serial_number, element)

new_atm = Atom('C' , np.array([0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 ]) , 0.00 , 1.00 , " " , 'CA' ,  atom_max +1  , 'C')

new_res.add(new_atm)  # works

# new_atm.set_parent(new_res)   # seems not to work  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


    
chainss[-1].add(new_res)

# new_res.set_parent(chainss[-1])  # seems not to work  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  


print('\n ________________________')  
for res in structure.get_residues() :
    
    print('res.get_full_id() : ', res.get_full_id() , ' res.id : ' , res.id)

    print('res.get_resname() : ', res.get_resname())
    
    print('res.get_segid() : ', res.get_segid())   

    print('res.get_parent() : ', res.get_parent())  
    

atom_list = structure.get_atoms() ## its actually a generator , that get emptied when cycled

print('\natom      ----------------> serial number')

for atom in atom_list:
    
    print( atom ,' -----------> ' ,  atom.get_serial_number() , atom.get_parent().resname , atom.get_parent().id[1])
    
    print(atom.get_full_id(),'\n')

print('\n ________________________')      


save_pdb = PDBIO()

save_pdb.set_structure(structure)

save_pdb.save('output.pdb' )
```

output as file pdb `output.pdb` :

```
ATOM      1  N   THR A   1      32.504  37.205  19.346  1.00 35.93           N  
ATOM      2  CA  THR A   1      33.806  36.685  19.869  1.00 33.83           C  
ATOM      3  C   THR A   1      35.000  37.216  19.097  1.00 34.05           C  
ATOM      4  O   THR A   1      34.831  37.956  18.112  1.00 37.45           O  
ATOM      5  CB  THR A   1      33.780  35.136  19.858  1.00 35.93           C  
ATOM      6  OG1 THR A   1      34.996  34.712  20.476  1.00 29.78           O  
ATOM      7  CG2 THR A   1      33.677  34.608  18.436  1.00 28.68           C  
ATOM      8  N   ASN A   2      36.222  36.900  19.493  1.00 27.70           N  
ATOM      9  CA  ASN A   2      37.466  37.312  18.870  1.00 26.38           C  
ATOM     10  C   ASN A   2      37.890  36.323  17.772  1.00 23.63           C  
ATOM     11  O   ASN A   2      37.108  35.426  17.477  1.00 26.11           O  
ATOM     12  CB  ASN A   2      38.573  37.472  19.903  1.00 26.18           C  
ATOM     13  CG  ASN A   2      38.854  36.188  20.687  1.00 23.57           C  
ATOM     14  OD1 ASN A   2      38.219  35.168  20.445  1.00 24.27           O  
ATOM     15  ND2 ASN A   2      39.763  36.310  21.648  1.00 25.69           N  
ATOM     16  N   ALA A   3      39.078  36.497  17.205  1.00 27.65           N  
ATOM     17  CA  ALA A   3      39.537  35.641  16.112  1.00 27.70           C  
ATOM     18  C   ALA A   3      39.734  34.176  16.518  1.00 27.15           C  
ATOM     19  O   ALA A   3      39.174  33.270  15.869  1.00 26.97           O  
ATOM     20  CB  ALA A   3      40.807  36.208  15.498  1.00 27.00           C  
TER      21      ALA A   3                                                       
ATOM     21  N   THR B   1      40.123  33.960  17.768  1.00 24.83           N  
ATOM     22  CA  THR B   1      40.236  32.608  18.357  1.00 21.65           C  
ATOM     23  C   THR B   1      38.868  31.997  18.531  1.00 22.46           C  
ATOM     24  O   THR B   1      38.571  30.833  18.173  1.00 22.18           O  
ATOM     25  CB  THR B   1      40.984  32.761  19.690  1.00 19.96           C  
ATOM     26  OG1 THR B   1      42.296  33.274  19.425  1.00 28.59           O  
ATOM     27  CG2 THR B   1      41.111  31.396  20.390  1.00 23.74           C  
HETATM   28  CA  XYZ B   2       0.100   0.100   0.100  1.00  0.00           C  
TER      29      XYZ B   2                                                       
END
```